# Cartopy is unable to download data

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to plot locations on a map using cartopy, here's my code

```
import cartopy.crs as crs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=crs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)

plt.show()
```

but I get this error :

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

which has something to do with this apparently

```
DownloadWarning: Downloading: https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip
  warnings.warn('Downloading: {}'.format(url), DownloadWarning)
```

Comment: The DNS entry for the server seems to be misconfigured. Try again later!

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69085393/1755432

Comment: I have the same problem with the latest version of cartopy to `0.19.0.post1`. Is there an opportunity to set the path by hand?

Comment: The old Natural Earth server is broken.  The next Cartopy version will download from AWS.  For discussion of ways to access the downloads in the meantime, see https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1849

Comment: Cartopy v0.20 has now been released, so this issue should be resolved by upgrading to that.

Answer (score 0):

`https://naciscdn.org` is not a valid DNS entry - DNS lookup fail with `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

The DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error typically appears in fine print under a message indicating that a website isn't responding and can't be loaded in your browser. This means that your browser failed to find the domain's internet protocol (IP) in the Domain Name System (DNS)